# Descargar automáticamente ficheros sin extensión con selenium

Tags: python, selenium

no consigo descargar un fichero que no tiene extensión con python y selenium.

He probado lo siguiente:

```
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet");
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain");
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv");
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/forced-download");
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "*/*");
```

Las he probado por separado, y ninguna de ellas me ha funcionado.

El navegador es firefox.

He probado con los mime-type de excel porque el fichero debería tener extensión xls, y el pop-up para guardar el archivo lo detecta como excel.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si es posible (pagina de dominio público sin acceso restringido) sería bueno que agregaras el link en concreto de de la web para poder reproducir el problema. ¿tienes alguna excepción?

Comment: @FJSevilla acceso solo para clientes, no vais a poder acceder. No hay ninguna excepción, simplemente se muestra el pop-up para guardar o abrir archivo.

Comment: Me lo suponía al ver que no agregas el link, pero por preguntar... XD . Voy a intentar  reproducir el problema, mientras tanto a ver si alguien que se enfrentara al mismo problema antes lo ve y puede responder, o si encuentras la solución no dudes en autorresponderte.

Comment: He estado probando cosas y he creado una respuesta con algunas conclusiones... Sin poder reproducir el problema por lo ya comentado, es como hacer disparos al aire, pero mira a ver si te ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La extensión no debe suponer ninguna diferencia en el lado del cliente, lo que si es esencial es que el Mime type que el servidor ofrece a través del header.

En teoría el [Mime type ofical](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet) para .xlsx debería ser:

> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

por lo tanto, debería ser:

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
options.set_preference(
    "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    )
 browser = webdriver.Firefox(options)
```

y para .xls:

> application/vnd.ms-excel

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
options.set_preference(
    "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
    "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    )
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options)
```

Puede que el servidor ante la no disponibilidad de la extensión lo envíe como:

> application/octet-stream

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
options.set_preference(
    "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
    "application/octet-stream"
    )
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options)
```

Pero en éste caso el pop-up no lo mostraría como un archivo de Ms-Excel. por lo que deduzco que el Mime-type posiblemente sea para `.xlsx` y no para `xls`.

Si nada funciona, intenta obtener el `Content-type` de la cabecera, para ver que es exactamente lo que el servidor dice enviar. En Firefox, en las herramientas de desarrollo, con la pestaña Red abierta (directamente se puede abrir con <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Mayús</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>) realiza la petición de descarga del documento (click en link o lo que sea), selecciona la petición adecuada en la lista y mira la parte de las cabeceras:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

* Click en la imagen para verla ampliada.

Hasta dónde yo se, no es posible indicar que descargue todos los archivos sin preguntar sin importar el tipo, en última instancia puedes intentar usar fuerza bruta y especificar todos los [Mime Types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) oficiales.

Comment: Funciona perfecto con el mime-type de xlsx. Muchas gracias!